# How to proper include JS libs (jqueryUI, jquery plugins) into DNN 5 module ?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I include jquery into my module with `DotNetNuke.Framework.jQuery.RequestRegistration();` and it works like expected.

Other scripts I include into my DNN portal via Page Settings/Advanced Settings/Page Header Tags.
They also get loaded, but they don't work as expected.

In my case I want to have tabs in one of my dnn modules and I'm using jqueryUI to do this. If I test this module outside of DNN it works like it should, but when installed into DNN something goes wrong. 
I get the tabs created but I can't switch betwen them. Actualy I see all of the content which should be in separated tabs in the same page.

[image]

This is my Js code from module.ascx file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#<%= pnlTabs.ClientID %>").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

how to correct this ? 
I think that problem is that all this different JS libs get mixed. So what is the correct way to include another JS libs into DNN module.

---

EDIT:
I found the problem. Can you help fix it ?

```
<li><a href="DesktopModules/OsControl/#dnn_ctr380_osControl_pnlProcesses">Processes</a></li>

<div id="dnn_ctr380_OsControl_pnlProcesses" style="text-align:left;">
```

Problem is that DNN prepends "DesktopModules/OsControl/" to the link in "li" element. How to prevent this or any other way around this ?

---

EDIT2:

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server" BulletStyle="NotSet" DisplayMode="HyperLink">
    <asp:ListItem Value="#OsControl_pnlProcesses">Processes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="#OsControl_pnlServices">Services</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="#OsControl_pnlEvents">Events</asp:ListItem>
</asp:BulletedList>
```

This is how I create links.

Comment: How are creating your links? If you're doing it in the .ascx file, DNN/.NET wouldn't be modifying the link. So you must be creating them programatically and doing it in a way that .NET is trying to resolve them.

Comment: I added the code for the links.

Comment: try replacing bulleted list with hardcoded <a href="OsControl_pnlProcess">Process</a>... and see if it works. I think it will work, and then you can find how to fix the bulletedlist links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first suggest to go through [this artilce](http://blog.theaccidentalgeek.com/post/2009/01/30/How-to-create-jQuery-Tabs-in-DotNetNuke.aspx)

The way you are adding jQuery and jQuery UI references may cause problems, please make sure jQuery.js is added before jQuery.ui.js.

If you think almost all the page requires jQuery, you can move your jQuery registration code to skin as well.

last thing is to add `console logging` to see the log messages in firebug console so that you can quickly track the script reference related problems

Comment: I added my findings into the original question. 
Can you now help me to solve this ? 
P.S. Thank you for the article.

Comment: show me the ascx code for <li><a href=..., it seems you are adding runat="server" to your links

Comment: Yes, I'm using runat="server", because later this will be dynamicly generated.

Comment: Thank you for useful links and advices. Now it works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the steps below, and you should be fine:

1. Login as HOST, go to Host > Portal Settings, expand jQuery Settings node, and check " Use Hosted jQuery version"
2. Add all other js references to Default.aspx file

Comment: -1 it is a VERY bad idea for a module to add js references to default.aspx.  Maybe get away with this if you will be the only one to ever use the module.  The various registerscript methods are still a much better to do the job.